# AWS Serverless Lambda Function: No module by name elasticsearch error

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am new to using Lambda in AWS and currently trying to execute some of the sample scripts given in different blogs to test how this all works in a server less environment.  One of the examples that I am trying to work on is to create a lambda function that gets triggered whenever an object is added to s3 bucket and stores the metadata of the object in elasticsearch.

For this purpose, I have created an elasticsearch domain, s3 bucket and started writing the lambda function.

I am using the inline code editor given in the lambda console, and have selected python3.6 as my runtime.  The following is the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pprint import pprint
import boto3
import json
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    imageid =  event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    print(imageid)
```

This code is yet to push data to elastic search, which I will write later.  However, I am getting the 'no module found` error for elasticsearch import.
The following is the error log when i test the above code.

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function'"
}

Request ID:
"a26249c3-00e2-11e9-83b0-ffc7719455cf"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: a26249c3-00e2-11e9-83b0-ffc7719455cf Version: $LATEST
Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named elasticsearch

END RequestId: a26249c3-00e2-11e9-83b0-ffc7719455cf
REPORT RequestId: a26249c3-00e2-11e9-83b0-ffc7719455cf  Duration: 0.42 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 25 MB
```

I was under the impression the server less environment by default load all the requisite libraries as they are invoked. However, when I looked up for more info on this error, I found some of them specified that source should be specified in zip file, while others indicate that the zip file is `When you use the ZipFile property to specify your function's source code and that function interacts`.

I find this confusing.  Do I have to install the elasticsearch module in a serverless environment or load it as a zip file?  How do I get the lambda function talk to elastic search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, AWS Lambda environment by default includes only [boto3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html) python library, for everything else you will need to build a zip file with all dependencies and upload it to the Lambda function.

There are (at least) 3 ways to do that:

1. Use AWS Cloud9 - [IDE in the cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/lambda-functions.html)
2. Write the code on your machine and configure a [CI/CD pipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codestar/latest/userguide/sam-tutorial.html) that will build the zip for you when you commit changes
3. Write code on your machine and [build/upload zip manually](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) - using the [SAM approach](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-build.html) is probably the most bullet-proof way to achieve that

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thank you....introduction to SAM was quite helpful.  I figured out how this could be done.

Comment: Great, enjoy the SAM! :)